# Github Action - Self hosted runner with customized image - not working as expected

Tags: docker, image, kubernetes, github, action

I have self-hosted runner that I customized its image by using -

```
FROM ghcr.io/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner:v2.307.1-ubuntu-20.04

RUN ...
RUN ..
```

However, when I use the image as self-hosted by changing the helm values to -
  `actionsRunnerRepositoryAndTag: "MyNewImage:latest"`

And then I start my self-hosted runner, I see that the pod itself is running successfully with my image.
But the runner itself seems to run on different container, or image, since it says that it runs on my pod, but when I shell to the pod I see my image files, and from the github action itself, all the packages, aliases does not exist.

Does github action run on docker in docker? or different image than the pod itself?

```
jobs:
  deploy_service:
    name: Deploy service
    runs-on: self-hosted
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: write

    steps:
      - name: node check
        shell: bash
        run: node --version
```

Not recognizing a pulumi command -

[image: From the github action]

[image: From the pod itself]

Answer (score 0):

Check your path, it's very likely that that base image you chose does not have the complete path you want, especially knowing the image firsthand. You will have to add things to your path if you want them to recognize.

A standard github runner will have a path like this:
`/snap/bin:/home/runner/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/runner/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`